# Fulltext index query become slowly when use row_number?

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, row-number, sql-optimization

The `table1` has huge rows and `field1` is text, so I create a fulltext-index of `field1`.

I run the sql below, it's very slowly, and the CPU to 100% all the way.

```
select * from (
    select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Order by [createtime] DESC) AS RowId 
    from table1
    where CONTAINS(field1, 'sometext')
) AS t1
where t1.RowId between 1 and 10
```

I remove `RowId` query, it becomes fast, less than 1s.

```
select * from (
    select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Order by [createtime] DESC) AS RowId 
    from table1
    where CONTAINS(field1, 'sometext')
) AS t1
```

Then I think it's about of SQLServer optimization, I try to add `zero` to `RowId` query field.

It goes fast! But why?

```
select * from (
    select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Order by [createtime] DESC) AS RowId 
    from table1
    where CONTAINS(field1, 'sometext')
) AS t1
where t1.RowId + 0 between 1 and 10
```

Comment: Why not `TOP 10`... `ORDER BY createtime DESC`?

Comment: Except from the rather rare cases where one could answer just by spotting suboptimal sql code, questions about performance should always come with the execution plan (pastetheplan is a handy site to share a plan). Else, we have no idea of whatever is going on on the background.